# Linq how to select only a small subset of a large result set?

Tags: .net, sql-server, linq, paging

I have a selection of a huge set of data and I would like to use a paging and to select only k elements, starting from the o'th element in the set, to support my paging. I don't like the idea of loading the whole data set with linq and then get only a subset, using the GetRange method, because the amount of elements can be very huge. For instance, if I have 6 000 000 rows in a table and want to show them, using a paging size of 10 and we are looking at the 5'th page, I would like to generate an SQL Server query, using Linq, which will select only 10 elements of my large table of 6 000 000 rows, because this way my application will be more efficient.

Does anybody know about a support for paging in Linq?

Thank you in advance,

Lajos Árpád.

Comment: Have you tried Take() & Skip()?

Comment: Possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380413/paging-with-linq-for-objects

Comment: Jon, I didn't try them, because I didn't know they existed and my google searches were not too successful about this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Skip` and `Take`.

```
collection.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Skip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357513.aspx) and [Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300906.aspx) methods

```
query = context.Table.Skip(number).Take(number);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Take and Skip.

```
var page = query.Skip(1000).Take(10);
```