# How does the ASP.NET 4.5 GridView.AllowCustomPaging property make this simpler?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, paging, .net-4.5

I have an ASP.NET 4 GridView control that uses the logic discussed in these 2 articles:

- [Efficiently Paging Through Large Amounts of Data](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/paging-and-sorting/efficiently-paging-through-large-amounts-of-data-vb)
- [Sorting Custom Paged Data](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/paging-and-sorting/sorting-custom-paged-data-vb)

How does the ASP.NET 4.5 `GridView.AllowCustomPaging` property make this simpler?

A link to an article on how to use it would be very welcome.

Answer (score 5):

In my recent experience, it doesn't.

Specifically: When implementing efficient GridView custom paging (retrieving only the required page of data from a very large database table) while using ASP.NET 4.5's [Model Binding](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/11/15/asp-net-webforms-model-binding-overview.aspx) system, the `GridView.AllowCustomPaging` property didn't enter into it.

Setting the [GridView.SelectMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.databoundcontrol.selectmethod.aspx) property causes Model Binding to be used, which gives us the "ObjectDataSource-style" functionality (as described in your links) without requiring an ObjectDataSource.  Within this approach, there are two options:

**(1) The method specified by `GridView.SelectMethod` returns an `IQueryable`**, e.g.:

```
public IQueryable<MyClass> MySelectMethod1()
{
    return myService.GetAll(someCriteria);
}
```

If you don't mind exposing an IQueryable to your Presentation Tier, then this is a very fast way of implementing very efficient paging.  At runtime, the framework automatically applies [Skip() and Take()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2380427/483655) methods to your source, based on the GridView's `PageIndex` and `PageSize` properties. Only the required page of results is returned from the database. Easy!

**(2) The method specified by `GridView.SelectMethod` returns some other bindable object**, e.g.:

```
public IList<MyClass> MySelectMethod2(int startRowIndex, int maximumRows, out int totalRowCount)
{
    totalRowCount = myService.GetCount(someCriteria);
    return myService.GetPage(someCriteria, startRowIndex, maximumRows);
}
```

By setting totalRowCount, we have now given the GridView all the information it needs to correctly render its Pager, while having retrieved only the required page of data from the database.

I had expected to use the [`VirtualItemCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.virtualitemcount.aspx) property (as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.allowcustompaging.aspx)), but as far as I can tell, the `totalRowCount` out-parameter obviates the `VirtualItemCount` property.

If **(1)** or **(2)** aren't implemented, then the GridView will throw an exception:
**When the DataBoundControl has paging enabled, either the SelectMethod should return an IQueryable or should have all these mandatory parameters : int startRowIndex, int maximumRows, out int totalRowCount**

So, we have implemented GridView custom paging in ASP.NET 4.5.... but with `GridView.AllowCustomPaging` and `GridView.VirtualItemCount` nowhere to be seen!