# Retrieve a list of object from database in sequence

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I am looking for a way to get a list of items in sequence, meaning that each calls will retrieve a set of database values in order.

Ok, that's not very clear, so let me show you.

Say that I have 200 entries of objects with a date properties, each entered from the beginning of February to today.

My first call would retrieve a set of the 20 latest entries, then the next call would retrieve entries 21-40, then the next call 41-60, and so on, as long as there's data to get.

I am using C# / Entity Framework and am familiar with Linq and the LinqKit, but that's a new challenge to me and am opened to any suggestions!

**EDIT** Ok, based on comments, my example is not adequate.

So let's say instead of having 200 I have 200 MILLIONS of entries, and more are pouring in. But, as I mentioned, I just want to load the first twenty, then the next twenty on each call, but I don't know how many times the user may make the call, so that's why I cannot "align" `Take(20)` calls since this is dynamic.

**EDIT2**

Here's a sample of code to guide you and me on my work :)

```
List<Book> listBooks = (from b in DbContext.Books
                                    orderby b.DateAdded
                                    select b).Take(count).ToList();
```

See, this chunk of code is not perfect because it will always return the 20 latests books added. But at the second call I would like to have the 20 next, then on the third call the 41-60 books, and so on.

**EDIT3**

After some research I have found something that might suit my needs:

[Paging with LINQ for objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380413/paging-with-linq-for-objects)

However I will need to work around a bit to figure out how to make this work.

Comment: @GrantWinney Yep, each row will have an ID as primary key, along with the datetime field and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are only 200, I recommend to you to get all the data with only one query to the database.

Then store in a for example a list, and then do something like.

```
list = list.OrderByDescending(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

Then to get the first 20 elements:

```
var result = list.Take(20);
```

And to get the 21-40:

```
var result = list.Skip(20).Take(20);
```

This way if insted of 20 you want more or less, you only need to convert 20 in a variable ;)

I hope this helps

Comment: Ok, yeah, I do understand your point and you are right in a way. I have placed a bad example, I will correct this.

Comment: As I mentioned in my call, it is a dynamic call and I cannot guess how much times this method will be called. I'd need a way to get the data by blocks of 20 entries, each time by their own filters.

Comment: I think that then you can use linq, maybe the same way I said, but instead of a list, do it making a call to the database. Somethink like when you in SQl Management Studio check a table, with SELECT TOP 20.. ORDER BY n.Name.. And opening a conection each time you want to retrieve something.BTW, the approach of my answer I think that will be useful if you have 20000000 of entries too ;)You can try it

Comment: Yeah, I think that something like this would be ok, but how could I do it in C#?

Comment: Try using SqlConnection (passing a connection string), then a SqlCOmmand, passing a query and a connection string, and then something like, var list = command.ExecuteNonQuery(). The qery something like, SELECT TOP 20 FROM xxxx WHERE Name = 'asdsa' ORDER BY Name or soemthing like that

Answer (score 1):

As has been alluded to, use `skip()` and `take()` along with variables to accomplish what you wish:

```
var numberOfBooksToGrab = 20;
var numberOfTimesYouHaveGrabbedBooks = 0;

List<Book> listBooks = (from b in DbContext.Books
                                    orderby b.DateAdded
                                    select b).Skip(numberOfBooksToGrab * numberOfTimesYouHaveGrabbedBooks)
                                             .Take(numberOfBooksToGrab)
                                             .ToList();
```

You will obviously need to update the `numberOfTimesYouHaveGrabbedBooks` variable each time you make the call, but that should be easy enough for you (and will depend on how the rest of your project is structured).