# Linq to entities, Paging in EF6: alternative for SkipWhile?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I want to use linq to show a sequence in pages, where operators can request to show the previous page or the next page. Each page has a constant page size.

Several questions on stackoverflow handle how to do this, a.o.
[Paging with LINQ for objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380413/paging-with-linq-for-objects?rq=1)

The solutions suggest using Skip and Take. This works fine as long as the sequence does not change while viewing it. But if items are inserted or removed while viewing a page, you'll miss items.

> Example: page size = 10 items. I am viewing page 8 (zero based) containing items 80 to 89. Obviously if I press pageup I want to see items 70 to 79. However, if someone inserted 5 items somewhere near item 25 (so way out of the page I am viewing), I will miss some items.

The cause of this is because the software thinks that page 8 is being viewed, while because of the insertions I am in fact viewing page 8.5.

So instead of using Skip(pagenumber * pagesize) I should use a function that returns the elements after a given element, or before a given item in the sequence. Normally SkipWhile(...) would be enough:

```
private static IEnumerable<T> ItemsAfter(this IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate, int pageSize)
{
   return source.Orderby(...)
                .SkipWhile(predicate)
                .Take(pageSize)
}
```

However SkipWhile is not recognized by LINQ to entities. So is there an alternative?

> Addition: What I want is: given an element from a sorted sequence, give me the next 10 elements (or the previous 10) I think the solution is somewhere near SQL Fetch Next and Fetch Prior, but haven't found a good explanation for it yet.

Comment: I do think it is a strange prerequisite. With your method, you could have a page 0, a page -1, a page -2 and so on (you are in page 2, someone inserts enough rows in page 1, and now your pages go to negative numbers)

Comment: So your not talking about a page number, you are talking about the previous 10 elements to show, or the next 10 elements to show.

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to come up with a replacement for `SkipWhile` because EF does not support any of the numbering functions either. Therefore everything based on relative order is hard.

Here, you probably can make use of the following query form:

```
   return source
            .Where(x => x.PositioningKey > lastSeenValue)
            .Orderby(x => x.PositioningKey)
            .Take(pageSize)
```

Comment: Actually, this is what I want: give me the pageSize number of items from a sorted sequence  starting at item lastSeenValue. However, If I have an ordered sequence, I can find the last seen value, for instance by Id, but how to find which values com after it?

Comment: Why doesn't `PositioningKey > lastSeenValue` work for that? Not sure I understand. Concretely, `Id > lastSeenId`.

Comment: Call me stupid, but I don't understand what you mean by PositioningKey and lastSeenValue. They are not linq members.

Comment: You want to sort by something, right? You want to show sorted by order number or whatever. So say "where x.OrderNumber > lastOrderNumberThatWasOnThePreviousPage". You need to track that value and to me it seemed you are already tracking that and wanting to use that for the SkipWhile call.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you mean. Suppose I have a sequence of Persons, sorted by surname, then by primary key. There are 40 John Doe in the sequence. I am currently displaying John Doe 5 to John Doe 15. Now I want to show the first 10 items after John Doe 15. My last found item had Surname John Doe. I know the primary key of my last found John Doe, so I can Find it again. but which Person comes after my last found John Doe?

Comment: You need to define a total sort order e.g. `Surname, ID`. You can then do `where x.Surname > sn || x.Surname == sn && x.ID > id`. This is ugly but works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104436/discussion-between-haralddutch-and-usr).