# How to list out items into multiple pages?

Tags: c#, .net, list, razor, items

I have database table with many records, I want to list every 10 items into 1 page depending on how many records there are.

My code so far lists them in a single page:

```
@foreach (var item in results)
{
    <a href="~/ViewInscription.cshtml?id=@item.RecordID">

    <div>Inscription : @item.RecordID</div> <br />
    <p style="float:left">@item.Text</p>
    <img src="@item.img1" />
    <br />

    </a>
}
```

Results is the result out of the SELECT statement:

The items will increase more often so there is no specific number of items

I'm building .net webpages using .net with c# Razor syntax

Comment: First result in google: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Turns out that  `asp.net mvc` offers a nuget package [PagedList.Mvc](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) for that.

Comment: im not building a MVC website

Comment: You will need to track your page size and current page and pass these into your backend. Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380413/paging-with-linq-for-objects