# How do I use Paging on a List<T>

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, iqueryable

I have the following and wish to implement paging but I get an error when doing so. I do not receive this error when I perform the paging directly on a query result that returns from LINQ as IQueryable, only when I create an IQueryable from a List (or IEnumerable)

> System.InvalidOperationException: The source IQueryable doesn't
>   implement IDbAsyncEnumerable. Only sources that implement
>   IDbAsyncEnumerable can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous
>   operations. For more details see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=287068

```
List<WeeklyBilling> wbs = new List<WeeklyBilling>();

            foreach (Trucks t in trucks)
            {
                WeeklyBilling wb = new WeeklyBilling();
                wb.Customer = t.Customer;
                wbs.Add(wb);
            }

            var wbitems = await wbs.AsQueryable<WeeklyBilling>()
               .OrderBy(input.Sorting)
               .PageBy(input)
               .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 6):

Refer to the [official docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn313107(v=vs.113).aspx).

> Because the Entity Framework queries make use of LINQ, the extension
> methods are defined on IQueryable and IEnumerable. However, because
> they are only designed to be used with Entity Framework, you may
> receive the following error **if you try to use them on a LINQ query
> that isn’t an Entity Framework query**.

You can also replace PageBy with the [Skip and Take extension methods or other solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380413/paging-with-linq-for-objects).

```
var wbitems = wbs.OrderBy(input.Sorting)
               .Skip(numberOfObjectsPerPage * pageNumber)
               .Take(numberOfObjectsPerPage)
               .ToList();
```