# How to apply skip and take in Datatable Asp.net Core 2.0

Tags: c#, datatable, asp.net-core-2.0, ienumerable, asenumerable

Is there any way to apply skip and take in Datatable in asp.net core 2.0. without converting to any class type?
I have used stored procedure to get data and convert to Datatable, I want to apply pagination in this Table, how can I do this?

Comment: something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380413/paging-with-linq-for-objects ?

Comment: @pix I don't have a class type, its a datatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use becuase it does not implement the `IEnumerable<T>`. But you can do this by using `AsEnumerable` extension method.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
IEnumerable<DataRow> rows = dt.AsEnumerable().Skip(10).Take(10);
```

Above solution works for .Net Core version >= 3

For .Net Core version 2. You need to install the package.

```
System.Data.DataExtensions
```

Comment: it support only in .net core 3 ? I am using .net core 2.0