# Linq to fetch all records if PageSize is 0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a Linq Query where I added pagination the default `pageNumber` value is 0 but I want to fetch all the records if no `pageSize` is passed.

```
await (from a in ctx.Appeals
join img in ctx.AppealImages on a.Id equals img.AppealId into appealImgGroup
from _img in appealImgGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
where
(a.Type == (int)AppealType.Appeal &&
(string.IsNullOrEmpty(search) || a.Name.Contains(search)))
select new Appeal
{
    Id = a.Id,
    Name = a.Name,
    ImagePath = _img.IsDefault == 1 ? _img.FilePath : null,
    TargetAmount = a.AmountToBeRaised.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(Configuration.UICulture)),
}).Skip(pageNumber).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Remove the `.Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();` bit. Then only apply `Take` if `pageSize` is > 0. Then apply `ToListAsync`.

Comment: Also keep in mind that without `OrderBy` the order of the data returned is in no way guaranteed (i.e. quasi-random). Which, given you are using `Skip`, is likely not what you want to happen.

Comment: Please, check below on Linq skip() and Take() usage. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380413/paging-with-linq-for-objects/2380427

Answer (score 3):

Like mjwills said, break your code up into parts:

```
var baseQuery = (from a in ctx.Appeals
join img in ctx.AppealImages on a.Id equals img.AppealId into appealImgGroup
from _img in appealImgGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
where
(a.Type == (int)AppealType.Appeal &&
(string.IsNullOrEmpty(search) || a.Name.Contains(search)))
select new Appeal
{
    Id = a.Id,
    Name = a.Name,
    ImagePath = _img.IsDefault == 1 ? _img.FilePath : null,
    TargetAmount = a.AmountToBeRaised.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(Configuration.UICulture)),
}).OrderBy( ... something ...);

if(pageSize > 0)
    baseQuery = baseQuery.Skip(pageNumber).Take(pageSize)

var result = await baseQuery.ToListAsync();
```

Note; you need to fix up the OrderBy

Comment: but then it will fetch all records and then it will do pagination but what I want is it should fetch paginated records

Comment: Where is the part where it fetches all records?

Answer (score 2):

You can only apply the `Take` and `Skip` if the `pageSize` is passed:

```
var query = await (from a in ctx.Appeals
join img in ctx.AppealImages on a.Id equals img.AppealId into appealImgGroup
from _img in appealImgGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
where
(a.Type == (int)AppealType.Appeal &&
(string.IsNullOrEmpty(search) || a.Name.Contains(search)))
select new Appeal
{
    Id = a.Id,
    Name = a.Name,
    ImagePath = _img.IsDefault == 1 ? _img.FilePath : null,
    TargetAmount = a.AmountToBeRaised.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(Configuration.UICulture)),
});

if (pageSize != null && pageSize > 0) {
  query = query.Skip(pageNumber).Take(pageSize);
}

return query.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Almost certainly `Skip(pageNumber)` is wrong too. Some form of multiplication with the pageSize will be needed.

Comment: yes!! I did the multiplication part and then the calculated value comes in pageNumber.and about the solution u provided I am aware of it but then it will fetch all the records and then it will do pagination what I want is it should fetch paginated records directly.

Answer (score 0):

My advise would be to create an extension method of any `IQueryable<T>`, that fetches page `pageNr` of size `pageSize`. Something like this:

```
public static ICollection<T> FetchPage<T>(this IQueryable<T> source,
    int pageNr, int pageSize)
{
    // TODO: implement
}
```

and the async version:

```
public static async Task<ICollection<T>> FetchPageAsync(this IQueryable<T> source,
    int pageNr, int pageSize) {...}
```

Usage would be:

```
var query = from a in ctx.Appeals  ...
select new Appeal
{
    ...
});

// Using page size 25, fetch page 5:
ICollection<Appeal> page5 = query.FetchPage(5, 25);

// Using page size 25, fetch page 20 async:
ICollection<Appeal> page5 = await query.FetchPageAsync(20, 25);    

// Fetch all Appeals:
ICollection<Appeal> allAppeals = query.FetchPage(5, 0);
```

If this is what you want, on with the implementation!

If you are not familiar with extension methods, read [Extension methods demystified](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/csharp/995/extension-methods-csharp)

The code for the sync and the async version are almost the same, so I'd create a common extension method first:

```
public static IQueryable<T>> QueryPage(this IQueryable<T> source,
    int pageNr, int pageSize)
{
    // TODO: check input: source not null, pageNr / pageSize not negative, etc

    // zero pageSize: return all:
    if (pageSize == null)
        return source;
    else
        return source.Skip(pageNr * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
}
```

Now that you've got this, the FechPage is a one-liner:

```
public static ICollection<T> FetchPage<T>(this IQueryable<T> source,
    int pageNr, int pageSize)
{
    return source.QueryPage(pageNr, pageSize).ToList();
}

public static async Task<ICollection<T>> FetchPageAsync<T>(this IQueryable<T> source,
    int pageNr, int pageSize)
{
    return await source.QueryPage(pageNr, pageSize).ToListAsync();
}
```

If you want a proper exception if source equals null, consider to call:

```
return QueryPage(source, pageNr, pageSize);
```

the `this` parameter in extension methods can also be used as a traditional parameter.