Call method that requires 'limit' and 'offset' in Linq
Maybe I'm asking some kind of nonsense, but I don't understand how to build LINQ query if third-party method requires parameters limit and offset and returns total and items.
What I've come to so far:
Enumerable.
Range(0, maxPages /*1000*/).
Select(i => i * maxLimit /*96*/).
Select(offset => new {
    offset = offset,
    result = api3.SearchQuery(searchTerm, maxLimit, offset)
}).
TakeWhile(a => a.offset <= a.result.total).
SelectMany(a => a.result.items).
ToArray()

Obviously, this query makes one extra call of api3.SearchQuery (and result will be result.items.Length == 0, so theoretically a.offset <= a.result.total can be replaced with a.result.items.Length > 0).
Is there any way to get rid of extra call?

Why use LINQ here instead of a simple loop that appends to a List?

i would assume you are talking about paging... take/skip check this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380413/paging-with-linq-for-objects

I think this will do the job: TakeWhile(a => a.offset < a.result.total)

@Denis seriously, why use LINQ at all ? It offers no benefits at all and makes the code harder to read and maintain. On top of that, it prevents the use of asynchronous calls. That API almost certainly has an asynchronous version (or should have). Instead of using LINQ like this, you can create an enumerator, either synchronous or asynchronous

You're correct, theoretically a.offset <= a.result.total can be replaced with a.result.items.Length > 0, but there is one issue.
TakeWhile evaluates the predicate before yielding elements. This means it will make one extra fetch even if you know there are no more results.
One way to get the precise control you need is to define a custom TakeUntil method, like this one, which is heavily inspired by the one from MoreLinq.
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> TakeUntil<TSource>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(predicate);

        return _(); IEnumerable<TSource> _()
        {
            foreach (var item in source)
            {
                yield return item;
                if (predicate(item))
                    yield break;
            }
        }
    }
}

You can simplify your method as follows:
Enumerable
    .Range(0, maxPages)
    .Select(i => i * maxLimit)
    .Select(offset => api3.SearchQuery(searchTerm, maxLimit, offset))
    .TakeUntil(a => a.Items.Count < maxLimit)
    .SelectMany(a => a.Items)
    .ToArray();


This is the answer. I've heard about MoreLINQ many times, but I haven't looked into what it is. Magnificent thing! Now I will use it in all my projects.

If you don't need any other LINQ extension from MoreLINQ then I would rather implement it myself.
